# Issues with CAS and sub-domains

Tags: java, cas

I've having some issues using CAS with sub-domains (Java client).

If I have the serverURL in web.xml config set to http://foobar.net:8080/, the service works fine with anything in the form of http://foobar.net:8080/xxxxx.

However, if I try to use a sub-domain, i.e. http://test.foobar.net:8080/xxxxx, it redirects me back to http://foobar.net:8080/.

The service GET variable on the CAS login page displays the URL without the subdomain (i.e. URL encoded form of http://foobar.net:8080/).

Any ideas of what is going wrong?

EDIT: Any ideas?

Comment: Central Authentication Server - a single sign-on server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm not very familiar with CAS Authentication Filters, however, based on the documentation, I don't see a way of configuring the filter in the way you need.

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+JA-SIG+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml

I do know that accessing the CAS library directly (via Java objects) would provide a work around, as you have control over the redirect process, but I don't think this is recommended. This doc (which is very, very out-of-date) may provide some guidance if you want to pursue it further:

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Using+the+basic+Java+CAS+Client+objects

You'd also need to take a look at the API doc for the version of the client you're using.

In any event, if you find a way to get this working, remember to create a new service for the sub-domain URL in your CAS service manager.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I did end up extending some of the CAS filters and classes. It's maybe not as clean as it could have been but I don't think there's been too much compromise on security. At this point, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Could you please extend in a response which filters and classes did you touch in order to get the subdomain?